# calculate the limit if necessary $f_α(x) = \frac{||x||_1^α}{||x||_2} $

Tags: limits

For $α ∈ ℝ$ let a family of functions $f_α : ℝ^3$ \ {$0$} $ → ℝ$ be defined by $f_α(x) = \frac{||x||_1^α}{||x||_2} $, where ||·||1 denote the Manhattan norm (1-norm) and ||·||2 the Euclidean norm. Check whether the limit of $f_α(x) $ for $ x = (x_1,x_2,x_3)^T → (0,0,0)^T$ as a function of $α$ exists and calculate the limit if necessary.

I really have no clue how it could work and would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence $(\frac 1ne_1) _{n\in \mathbb N}$. We get
$$ f(\frac 1ne_1) =\frac{\frac{1}{n^\alpha}}{\frac 1n}=n^{1-\alpha}$$
Hence,  $f(\frac 1ne_1))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges, if and only if $\alpha>1$.

Now you have to prove, that $\alpha>1$ suffices. Find $c>0$, such that $\|x\|_1\leq c\|x\|_2$ for all $x\in \mathbb R^3$. Then estimate $f(x) $ in terms of $\|x\|_2$.